# Stack and Heap allocation

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm looking into the memory model a little more and am struggling with understanding how many heap's exist in a process.

So if we have 1 process with 5 threads in it, am I correct in saying that we'd have 5 stacks and 1 heap?

If so, can the threads access one another's stacks (or is this exactly why they have separate Stacks, to prevent corruption), and if there's just 1 heap, then obviously they all access this heap, hence the need for locking with multiple threads? Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, each thread has its own stack.  That's a hard necessity, the stack keeps track of where a method returns after it finishes, it stores the return address.  Since each thread executes its own code, they need their own stack.  Local variables and method arguments are stored there too, making them (usually) thread-safe.

The number of heaps is a more involved detail.  You are counting 1 for the garbage collected heap.  That's not entirely correct from an implementation point of view, the three generational heap plus the Large Object Heap are logically distinct heaps, adding that up to four.  This implementation detail starts to matter when you allocate too much.

Another one that you can't entirely ignore in managed code is the heap that stores static variables.  It is associated with the AppDomain, static variables live as long as the AppDomain lives.  Commonly named "loader heap" in .NET literature.  It actually consists of 3 heaps (high frequency, low frequency and stub heap), jitted code and type data is stored there too but that's getting to the nitty gritty.

Further down the ignore list are the heaps used by native code.  Two of them are readily visible from the Marshal class.  There's a default process heap, Windows allocates from it, so does Marshal.AllocHGlobal().  And there's a separate heap where COM stores data, Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem() allocates from it.  Lastly any native code you interop with will have its own heap for its runtime support.  The number of heaps used by that kind of code is bounded only by the number of native DLLs that get loaded into your process.  All of these heaps exist, you barely ever deal with them directly.

So, 10 heaps minimum.

Answer (score 12):

In short, **yes**.

All threads in a process share the same heap, so they can exchange data. Each thread has it's own stack that relates to the current code execution on this thread.

A very good resource on threading is here: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

> A thread is analogous to the operating system process in which your
>   application runs. Just as processes run in parallel on a computer,
>   threads run in parallel within a single process. Processes are fully
>   isolated from each other; threads have just a limited degree of
>   isolation. In particular, threads share (heap) memory with other
>   threads running in the same application. This, in part, is why
>   threading is useful: one thread can fetch data in the background, for
>   instance, while another thread can display the data as it arrives.

Answer (score 4):

Threads are separate instruction streams running simultaneously in the same virtual address space of a single process. Heap is a big chunk of memory that the system gives to each process for its own private usage. Processes can adjust their heap size and can use the heap space as they deem it necessary. Threads can collaborate on using this heap space and can also allocate additional private memory regions known as *thread local storages* (TLSes).

Since all threads share the same virtual address space, they can access each other's stacks memory directly. This means that one thread can pass a variable on its stack as an argument to a function running in some other thread. But still thread stacks are separate in that one thread never pushes or pops values into some other thread's stack but only into its own stack space. Since stacks on x86 and x86-64 grow downward, there is a special page at the bottom of each thread's stack memory - the so called *guard page*. The stack fault occurs if the guard page is ever reached while operating the stack.

In unmanaged languages as C and C++ every part of the process memory can be accessed at will through the usage of pointers. One thread can completely mess up with the content of another thread's stack and thus crash the second thread (and the process as a whole). In C# these sorts of things cannot happen outside of `unsafe` blocks since stacks are mananged by the CLR.

Comment: _one thread can pass a variable on its stack as an argument to a function running in some other thread_ - how would you do that exactly?

Comment: With Win32 threads you could just start a new thread and pass the address of a local variable in the current thread as the thread argument. You could also use `PostThreadMessage` to send a message to an already running thread.

Comment: You either pass a variable by value or pass it by address using pointers in C/C++ (or aliases in C++ which are still implemented as pointers).

Answer (score 2):

This is implementation defined, but let's talk about most popular modern OSes, since you add C# tag.

> how many heap's exist in a process.

Usually 1 per process.

> So if we have 1 process with 5 threads in it, am I correct in saying that we'd have 5 stacks and 1 heap?

Yes. Each thread consumes 1MB of virtual address space straight away for thread stack.

> If so, can the threads access one another's stacks (or is this exactly why they have separate Stacks, to prevent corruption), and if there's just 1 heap, then obviously they all access this heap, hence the need for locking with multiple threads? Am I understanding this correctly?

Yes, modern environments are very well sandboxed, hence you cannot access other thread stack from another thread directly.

Comment: Lukas did you saw Jakub-Konecki answer ? How does it correlate with "...hence you cannot access other thread stack" ?? And why 'locking' mechanism exists ?

Comment: You can surely access the stack of one thread from another, though its way better to avoid such direct comms and use an object queue that is accessible from both threads.

Comment: Nitpicking: A process has the (normal) Managed Heap, a Large Object Heap and you could consider the Unmanaged Heap to be #3.

Comment: @MartinJames - Accessing another threads stack certainly isn't easy or common. With pointers maybe.

Comment: @MartinJames in Native code sure, in .Net is complicated. By default is off. With "unsafe" is possible